# Cannot create New Team Project with TFS power tools 2008

Tags: tfs, project, tfs-power-tools

### I am in the process of creating a new team project by executing the tfpt createteamproject command as a background process in my .net application. However, I get the following exception from the log :

```
2009-10-06 17:02:10Z | Module: Internal | Team Foundation Server proxy retrieved | Completion time: 0.140274 seconds
```

2009-10-06 17:02:10Z | Module: Internal | The template information for Team Foundation Server "http://vm-devt9:8080/tfs" was retrieved from the Team Foundation Server. | Completion time: 0.015586 seconds
2009-10-06 17:02:10Z | Module: Engine | Thread: 1 | New project will be created with the "MSF for Agile Software Development v5.0" methodology
2009-10-06 17:02:10Z | Module: Engine | Retrieved IAuthorizationService proxy | Completion time: 0.15586 seconds
---begin Exception entry---
Time: 2009-10-06 17:02:10Z
Module: Engine
Event Description: TF30226: User did not have project creation permissions
Exception Type: System.Security.SecurityException
Exception Message: TFXXXXXX: You cannot create team projects with this version of the Visual Studio Team System web service. Please upgrade your client to a version compatible with Visual Studio Team System 2010.
Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Proxy.AuthorizationService.CheckPermission(String objectId, String actionId)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.SecurityHelper.UserHasCreatePermissions(ELeadLogger log)
--- end Exception entry ---

2009-10-06 17:02:10Z | Module: Engine | Thread: 1 | TF30172: You do not have permission to create a new team project.
2009-10-06 17:02:10Z | Module: BatchTeamProjectCreator | Thread: 1 | Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.ProjectCreationException: TF30172: You do not have permission to create a new team project.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.EngineStarter.CheckPermissions()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.EngineStarter.CreateProject()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.BatchTeamProjectCreator.CreateProject()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.BatchTeamProjectCreator.BatchCreateTeamProject()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.BatchTeamProjectCreator.BatchCreateTeamProject(String teamProjectCreationSettingFile, String& logFileFullPath)

### 2009-10-06 17:02:10Z | Module: BatchTeamProjectCreator | Thread: 1 | Team Project Batch Creation failed.

I also got problems with the double quotes when specifying the process template (I use the MSF for Agile Software Development v5.0)

I have all admin and team project creation permissions setup, but can anyone point out wats going wrong here?

Thanks,
Tara.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised there's a workaround here. VSTS 2010 has a built in command to automate project creation so am gonna try this out. Cannot wait for Power tools till it's shipped with VS 2010..:D

Answer (score 0):

I would respectfully suggest that you don't have full rights set up! Can you do it from the UI?

Edit just reread.

version of the Visual Studio Team System web service. Please upgrade your client to a version compatible with Visual Studio Team System **2010**

Does this mean that you're using a 2010 command prompt?

Edit:

Since you're using the TFPT -can you use the powershell scripts? I suspect they'll fail the same way. Short of asking MS as to when the TFPT will be ported to 2010 I'm afraid I'm at a bit of a loss - sorry.

Comment: I needed just the rights to create a new project, sharepoint portal services and SQL reporting services. Besides, this is just a test TFS server.I need to be able to create projects silently this way. Yes I can create from the UI. When I try directly using the VS cmd prompt, it gives me this exception, but when i try through my app, it says " Unexpected error occurred when creating a team project.
System.ArgumentException: Process template "MSF" does not exist on team foundation server "http://vm-devt9:8080/tfs"."

Comment: No. I am using VS 2008 command prompt on a TFS 2010 server..This lack of compatibility seems to be the problem. Any solutions?